# Can I add placeholder or reference to enum list into schema description according to openapi 3.0 specs?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Schema description needs to be updated with enum list defined in same openapi.yaml file. Here's an example in **pseudocode** and desirable outcome:

```
enum:
  - John
  - Doe

description: {enumList} is the name
```

outcome
`John Doe is the name`

The question is whether some sort of this approach is possible. Schema description supports markdown syntax, but I couldn't find mechanisms that allow to achieve such result

edit: theoretically it can be an array of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither OpenAPI Specification nor Markdown support templated descriptions out of the box. But you can write a script that would parse an OpenAPI file and substitute your custom templating syntax with the desired values. There are [OpenAPI parsers](https://openapi.tools/#parsers) for different programming languages, or you could use a YAML/JSON processor such as [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/).

Comment: openapi.yaml file in this case is formed in order to visualise its APIs resources by service I have no control of. I just upload a .yaml file and service does it's magic. 
Your suggestion implies If I had control over it?

Comment: _"I just upload a .yaml file..."_ So you have an OpenAPI YAML file. Before uploading it to that service, you could process the file with a script to replace `{enumList}` with the corresponding text.